# SQL Tickets sold - Last 30 Days - use Where or Having?

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

How many tickets were sold for each route and each day, for the routes sold in the last 30 days from current day?

```
SELECT COUNT(TICKET_ID) NUMBER_TICKETS, ROUTE_CODE, FLIGHT_DATE 
FROM TICKETS 
WHERE (DAYS(CURRENT DATE)- DAYS(FLIGHT_DATE))<=30
GROUP BY ROUTE_CODE, FLIGHT_DATE
```

Should this be WHERE or HAVING? I am not sure which way is correct?

Comment: in the WHERE-clause

Comment: If you wanted to see only those where the count(Ticket_ID) is > 30 then you'd use the having.  If you're wanting to reduce what is counted, where clause.  Put another way: the having is a where clause that executes after the aggregation is done.  If I tried to put count(Ticket_ID) > 30 in the where clause the DB engine would throw an error as it hasn't done the count yet.  Order of operations in SQL is wierd  FROM, Joins, Where, Group by, Select, then Having and order by (and a few other steps not in your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it in the WHERE.

Here is the best way to understand this --

The WHERE clause is used before the GROUP BY

The HAVING clause is used after the GROUP BY

So -- you want to group items in the last 30 days -- that happens before the group.

Answer (score 0):

where is the right command, consider to use "datediff" for calculate 30 days

Answer (score 0):

the WHERE clause is used to specify a condition for filtering records **before any groupings are made**
the HAVING clause is used to specify a condition for filtering values **from a group**

in this case, the where clause is used for filtering the condition, not the group.
You should use "having",for example,  if you wanted to check the ticket_id.